# How can I force TypeScript to check a cy.task argument's type?

Tags: typescript, cypress

If I specify type of a Cypress task as follows:

```
// X and Y are some types
function a(arg: X): Y { ... }

...
on('task', { a })

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      task(event: 'a', arg: X): Chainable<Y>;
    }
  }
}
```

I've found that TypeScript unfortunately happily accepts

```
cy.task('a', notAnX)
```

because it falls back to the default definition from `cypress.d.ts`

```
task<S = unknown>(event: string, arg?: any, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable>): Chainable<S>
```

Can I change my declaration in some way to make this an error?

EDIT: There is a similar request in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19064, but nobody suggests any currently working solutions, so my guess is that it's impossible for now (except for copying `cypress.d.ts` and removing that overload).

Comment: Why did you add the declaration later in the file?

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR It's next to the `on('task', { a })` to remember it needs to be changed when tasks are added/removed. But I must admit I don't understand why the location would matter.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it should be possible to do the following if you use TypeScript ESLint with type information:

1. Declare `interface TypeError {}`
2. Add a new `task` overload together with the actual tasks:

   ```
   task(event: string, arg?: any, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable>): TypeError
   ```
3. Add a [custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) to ESLint to disallow any uses of `TypeError`.

My initial attempt was to use `never` but some cases I would prefer not to type-check still type-checked.